# WebSocket can't establish a connection to the server

Tags: symfony, websocket, phpwebsocket, ratchet

I try to make a simple chat page on my symfony project by WebSocket.
First I used [React-php](http://reactphp.org/) library, it perfectly works on terminal but when I try to connect it to browser I faced this error on chrome:

```
Uncaught Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11
```

and on firefox

```
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:8000/.
```

Next I used [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/) library and follow the tutorial but still the same problem, work on terminal, error on browser.
I use `telnet localhost 8000` on terminal and javascript on browser is

```
var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8000');
conn.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e.data);
};
conn.send('Hello World!');
```

the server code for React

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
$loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
$socket = new React\Socket\Server($loop);
$conns = new \SplObjectStorage();
$socket->on('connection', function ($conn) use ($conns) {
    $conns->attach($conn);
    $conn->on('data', function ($data) use ($conns, $conn) {
        foreach ($conns as $current) {
            if ($conn === $current) {
                continue;
            }
            $current->write($data);
        }
    });
    $conn->on('end', function () use ($conns, $conn) {
        $conns->detach($conn);
    });
});
$socket->listen(8000);
$loop->run();
```

and server code for Ratchet

```
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
require __DIR__ . '/chat.php';
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use MyApp\Chat;
$server = IoServer::factory( new WsServer( new Chat() ), 8000);
$server->run();
```

Another thing is client page url is `localhost/X/chat` and server `localhost/X/server`, I tried `ws://localhost:8000/X/server` but still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call `send` before the connection is established. You need to bind to the `onopen` event:

```
var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8000');
conn.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e.data);
};
conn.onopen = function () {
    conn.send('Hello World!');
};
```

This should fix your issue.

Comment: If connection be right, `conn.send()` is usable. However I tried your code but still doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "Doesn't work"? Do you get a new error? If so, I answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in cURL ext. solved.

Comment: how did you solved it? what exactly did you to get it works?

Comment: after 7 years i have no clue what have i done :) 
based on comment, maybe i have installed curl extension for php

Comment: I imagined that you don't remember, but I said to try anyway .. I'm desperate that my websocket doesn't connect and it's not a problem from cURL from what I notice ..

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, `React\Socket` opens a plaintext TCP / IP connection.

You can use any plaintext TCP/IP client to connect to your server, such as telnet or any other TCP/IP library.

If you want to use a WebSocket client, such as the one provided by your browser, you will have to use a WebSocket server. Ratchet is a WebSocket server that builds on top of this project.

Look this
https://github.com/reactphp/socket/issues/142